# how do I set my Iframe in screen for mobile devices

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

```
My css for Iframe:

position: absolute;
right: 0;
top: -100px;
z-index: 1;
height: 110%;
width: 100%;
border: none;
overflow-y: auto;
overflow-x: hidden;
```

This is my CSS for Iframe screen on my website, but in mobile devices, I have to scroll the Iframe screen to see the full website.
Note: making the iframe responsive is not in my hand.

Comment: in desktop view did the scroll appears ?

Answer (score 0):

The bootstrap method. Use an iframe or video element in it.

```
<div class="embed-16by9">
  <iframe src="..."></iframe>
</div>
```

with responsive css

```
embed-16by9 {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.embed-16by9::before {
  display: block;
  content: "";
  padding-top: 56.25%; /* ratio 16:9 */
}
.embed-16by9 iframe,
.embed-16by9 video {
  width: 100%;
  border: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0;
  height: 100%;
}
```